# Laravel - bitbucket pull / push

Tags: laravel, git, bitbucket, push

I'm totally confused how I should add my laravel project to my bitbucket profile and repository. That project that I am adding should be used by me and my college colleagues and they all have to push their changes to the project. How it works ? And how can I pull those changes to my local project on my PC ?
Please help. Thanks!

Comment: This is something you could've googled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by creating a repository on bitbucket. Then navigating to the project on your local environment and running the following commands:

```
cd my-laravel-project
git init
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:yourusername/my-laravel-app.git
git add -A
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin master
```

Colleagues can then clone the repository using the following command:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:yourusername/my-laravel-app.git
cd my-laravel-app
```

after making changes they can be committed using:

```
git status
git add -A
git commit -m "Fix database connection"
git push
```

The changes made by colleagues can be retrieved using:

```
git pull
```

Merging can be achieved by first pulling the target branch into the current branch then comparing and committing the changes:

```
git pull origin master
// review the changes
git add -A
git commit -m "Merge changes"
git push
```

Comment: Thank you sir. How can I pull all the changes my colleagues have done ?

Comment: Updated the answer, by including `git pull` @Milos